# inflates 2 views using same xml:second view contains properties of first view

Tags: android, android-button, layout-inflater

When changing the text of TextView of the first view, the textView's text of the second view shows the text of both TextViews, one on top of the other.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout rl=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    View v1=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);
    View v2=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

    TextView myTextView1= (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    TextView myTextView2= (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    myTextView1.setText("str1");
    myTextView2.setText("str2");


    rl.addView(v1);
    rl.addView(v2);









}
```

Comment: Layout? Code? Something to see?

Comment: you are using framelayout, is the goal to have the views overlapping?

Comment: No, I use it in tabs, each view belongs to different tab, I didn't post all my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the issue is because you are using a framelayout so the subviews will overlap.  If you switch that framelayout to a linearlayout for example I imagine the results will be as you expect according to the textviews.

Comment: I can't use LinearLayout, each 1 of my 2 views belongs to different tab, they are not supposed to overlap, seems like system doesn't clean the screen when moving from 1 tab to another.

Answer (score 0):

very simple.. 1. you have to use *`append`* property rather than `settext` in second textview
2nd you can use extras to pass using intent or use getter setter method like

```
public static void setstr_name(String str_name) {
        GlobalVariable.str_name = str_name;
    }

    public static String getstr_name() {
        return str_name;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need to pass intent, what is the global variable stands for?